# Quickblox q-municate activity landing xml

Tags: android, xml, quickblox

Having issue with activity landing xml file for the quickblox q-municate android sdk.

Error is stating:

> Error:(7, 17) Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/').

I know I have to place a location under "android:id="@+id/" but not sure what put in:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_image"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/">
```

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/your_id"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_image"
android:orientation="vertical">
```